# putImageData not working checked existing questions

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
ctx.drawImage(preview,0,0, preview.width, preview.height)
var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0,0, preview.width, preview.height).data;
ctx.putImageData(opaque(ctx.createImageData(10,10)), 0,0)
```

The opaque function sets the alpha data to 1. so as to pain a black square of 10*10.

```
function opaque(imgData){
        for(var i=0, data = imgData.data; i<data.length; i=i+4){            
            data[i+3] = 1;
        }       
        return imgData;
    }
```

But my canvas looks white.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

If you want to draw a black square, use context.fillRect(...). It's more efficient than manipulating imageData.

If you want to make parts of your imageData wholly transparent, you need to set the alpha channel to 0. The alpha channel is in range [0..255], with zero meaning wholly transparent, and 255 meaning wholly opaque.

Though I haven't actually run it, from reading your opaque function, all it seems to do is make its imageData argument's pixels almost wholly transparent.